# Magento2.4.2: How to add Multi Select option for Payment Method filter in sales order Grid?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4, payment-methods

I want to add multi Select option for payment method filter, any idea ,
[image]

**thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Vendor/MultiselectFilters/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="payment_method">
            <settings>
                <filter>multiselect</filter>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Payment Method</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <filterSelect name="payment_method" provider="${ $.parentName }" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select"
                          template="ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select">
                <settings>
                    <options class="Magento\Payment\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Method\Options"/>
                    <caption translate="true">Select</caption>
                    <label translate="true">Payment Method</label>
                    <dataScope>payment_method</dataScope>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

**Let me know if it works?**

Comment: Thanks, yes it works